# GET http://localhost:8080/images/1606504376_preview_wonder-day-among-us-21.png 404

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Im writing forum now and i have a task with display user's image on his html page. Problem is that when i upload image to hard disk and refresh the page this error pops up:GET http://localhost:8080/images/1606504376_preview_wonder-day-among-us-21.png 404. The images are stored in /resources/static/images.In other words image is stored on hard disk and browser thinks that the link is null but its not true. if i restart tomcat the image displays correctly. What could be the error? Thanks
Method of controller to display user's view page:

```
@GetMapping("/view")
    public String getViewPage(Model model, Principal principal) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "viewPage";
    }
```

Method of rest controller to post image to hard disk:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadImage")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                            Principal principal) throws IOException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        imageService.upload(file, user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

View Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Страница пользователя</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uploadFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table th:border="10" th:width="500" th:height="300" th:align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Почта/логин
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Отображаемый никнейм
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Аватарка
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table th:border="10" th:width="500" th:height="300" th:align="center">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${user.getEmail()}">
            Название
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${user.getUsernameForOtherUsers()}">
            Отображаемый никнейм
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img th:src="@{${user?.getImage()?.getShortPath()} + ${user?.getImage()?.getName()}}" alt="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <label path="file">Выберите файл для загрузки</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery script to upload image to server:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submitButton").click(function(event) {

        // Stop default form Submit.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Call Ajax Submit.

        ajaxSubmitForm();

    });

});

function ajaxSubmitForm() {

    // Get form
    var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

    var data = new FormData(form);


    $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/uploadImage",
        data: data,

        // prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 1000000,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            $("#result").html(data);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", false);
            $('#fileUploadForm')[0].reset();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $("#result").html(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log("ERROR : ", jqXHR.responseText);
            $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", false);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading your file to a different folder (e.g., `/tmp/received-files`) and adding that folder to the application profile using [a `file:/` resource string prefix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.23/reference/html/core.html#resources-resource-strings):

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,file:/tmp/received-files
```